# Add a node to Circular Linked List which contains only one node

Tags: linked-list, circular-list

I only heard about linked lists a couple weeks ago, and now I'm into circular linked lists. The question is simple: In a circular list that only has one element, is the next node himself, i.e. does it link back to himself or to null? Because if I try to add a new element in the next node position I will also be overwriting the present node (the first if the list has only one element and it links back to himself).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **In a circular list that only has one element, is the next node himself, i.e. does it link back to himself or to null?**

The next node is himself, not `NULL`.

[image]

> **if I try to add a new element in the next node position I will also be overwriting the present node...**

If it currently only has one node, to add a new node, it is equivalent to add the note to its end.

```
New->next = Cur;    // same as: New->next = Rear->next;
Prev->next = New;   // same as: Rear->next = New;
Rear = New;
```

---

Check out [this presentation](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.ust.hk%2F~horner%2Fcomp104%2Fnotes%2FlinkedListCircular.ppt&ei=W-pMU_y7O9Lh8AWigoLQAQ&usg=AFQjCNHm0i_Uy0_75JSn5EvX4QT3RVyx-A&sig2=-cLmsHb2keOmcSHW7XV9AA) for more details.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know how to verify if the next node of the first one is himself. I try to do this:

`this.base = new NodeCLL<T>(elem,this.base);
if(this.base.next.equals(this.base)) System.out.println("bla");`

inside of an add method, and it gives nullpointerexception

Comment: @user3267330 You can check their address.

Comment: Isn't it what the .equals does? It checks (by default) if the objects are the same, but it is giving me nullpointer exception. You answered my question about the concept of circular linked lists, maybe I'll make other post java specific.

Comment: @user3267330 I am familiar to Jave. In C++, you can just check `if (new == real)`.

Comment: I think I know what my problem is. When I define `this.base = new NodeCLL<T>(elem,this.base);` this.base is null before being defined so I will have this.base with an element that I give and the next node won't be this.base but null. I will have to redo that part. That may be why I'm having null pointer exception when I try to campare the two nodes.